# Why header is usually position: fixed?

Tags: html, css, header

Is there a reason why in many tutorials, on many websites or even in google search results, header is often `position: fixed` rather than `absolute`? What are the pros to that approach?

Comment: Ask those that wrote the tutorials; their choice is theirs to explain. But I'd imagine it's to keep the header visible on the screen regardless of the scroll-position of the site.

Comment: It all relates to scrolling. when you scroll with fixed , you still see the header at the top while in absolute  - you dont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed makes the header stay where it is on the screen all the time, even if you scroll down the page. Absolute lets you place an element exactly where you want and removes it from the flow of the page, but you can scroll away from it.

For more detail and a much better explanation, read: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: Thank you. I understand the general concept of `position` and difference between types, but couldn't understand on insisting having header 'fixed'. I checked on another browser and understood the issue with scrollbar. Still, making sure that no elements are chaotically pushed outside the screen, and having header outside the flow of main content as `relative`, works fo me so much better, at least for the time being.